# Generating XML Dynamically in PHP - Parsing Error

Tags: php, xml

I am generating `xml` file dynamically and getting error when i include **newstext**. `Error: XML Parsing Error: undefined entity` !   [image: ERROR]
By remove **newstext** `xml` generates perfectly. Here is the code i am using.

```
$sqlNews    =   "SELECT * FROM news";

$runSqlNews =   mysql_query($sqlNews);

while ($rowSqlNews  =   mysql_fetch_array($runSqlNews)) 
    $arrSqlNews[]   =   $rowSqlNews;


    header('Content-type: text/xml');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Cache-control: private');
    header('Expires: -1');
    echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>";

    echo '<xml>';

for($i=0;$i<count($arrSqlNews);$i++) 
{
    echo "<news>";
        echo "<newsId>".$arrSqlNews[$i][id]."</newsId>";
        echo "<newsAuthor>".$arrSqlNews[$i][news_author]."</newsAuthor>";
        echo "<newsText>".$arrSqlNews[$i][news_text]."</newsText>";
        echo "<description>".$arrSqlNews[$i][news_description]."</description>";
        echo "<image>".$arrSqlNews[$i][news_image]."</image>";
    echo "</news>";       
}
    echo '</xml>';
```

Hope my question is clear.  Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: PHP has a couple of extensions to generate XML that take care of generating valid syntax...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider adding [CDATA](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp) tags whenever you work with strings, as special characters can break your XML parse.

```
echo "<newsText><![CDATA[".$arrSqlNews[$i][news_text]."]]></newsText>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
echo "<newsText><![CDATA[".$arrSqlNews[$i][news_text]."]]></newsText>";
```

It will prevent the browser from parsing tags from that field content.

Comment: This thing working fine on my local server.  When i upload to my site i got this error (XML Parsing Error: no element found).  What might be the reason